# Elastic Search Should clause

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm trying to fetch users from ES based on the status of some of the fields.
I have 5 fields whose status I want to check and if any of these fields have the failed status I want to fetch that record. Since it's an OR condition between these 5 fields I was trying to use **should** in ES and adding **terms** to it. But it returns records of those users who don't match the criteria as well.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "segment_status.updated_at": {
                        "from": "2021-01-24",
                        "to": null,
                        "include_lower": true,
                        "include_upper": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "should": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "segment_status.bse_status": [
                        2,
                        3,
                        4
                      ],
                      "boost": 1
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "segment_status.nse_status": [
                        2,
                        3
                      ],
                      "boost": 1
                    }
                  }
                  
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                "boost": 1
              }
            },
            "path": "segment_status",
            "ignore_unmapped": false,
            "score_mode": "avg",
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "marked_failed_manually": {
              "value": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "segment_status.updated_at": {
        "order": "asc",
        "mode": "min",
        "nested_filter": {
          "term": {
            "segment_status.segment_type": {
              "value": "CASH",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        "nested_path": "segment_status"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That is the query generated by the code. I'm using spring boot to build the query.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, I tried this query and it seems to work.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
        "nested":{
          "query":{
            "bool":{
              "must" : [
                {
                  "range" : {
                    "segment_status.updated_at" : {
                      "from" : "2021-08-30",
                      "to" : null,
                      "include_lower" : true,
                      "include_upper" : true,
                      "boost" : 1.0
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "path" : "segment_status",
          "ignore_unmapped" : false,
          "score_mode" : "avg",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "segment_status.bse_status": [
                        2,
                        3
                      ],
                      "boost": 1
                    }
                  }
                  
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                "boost": 1
              }
            },
            "path": "segment_status",
            "ignore_unmapped": false,
            "score_mode": "avg",
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "marked_failed_manually": {
              "value": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "segment_status.updated_at": {
        "order": "asc",
        "mode": "min",
        "nested_filter": {
          "term": {
            "segment_status.segment_type": {
              "value": "CASH",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        "nested_path": "segment_status"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```